# Order users by days until birthday

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table with people and their birth dates. I want to SELECT them ordered by the "**number of days until next birthday**".

I have tried with the `DAYOFYEAR()` function:

```
SELECT id, DAYOFYEAR(datebirth)-DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) AS daystobd
FROM users ORDER BY daystobd;
```

But... I got negative `daystobd` if the birthday has passed this year. The intention is to have those listed at the end.

Any idea ?

EDIT: daystobd should reflect the real number of days until **next** birthday

NEW EDIT:

I managed to do it with UNION, but I think surely there is a more "elegant" way to do this.

```
SELECT id, DAYOFYEAR(datebirth)-DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) AS daystobd
FROM users WHERE DAYOFYEAR(datebirth)-DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())>=0 
UNION
SELECT id, 365+DAYOFYEAR(datebirth)-DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) AS daystobd
FROM users WHERE DAYOFYEAR(datebirth)-DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())<0 ORDER BY daystobd
```

Comment: ORDER BY CASE WHEN datstobd<0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,daystobd

Comment: @Mihai that doesn't solve the negative `daystobd`. next birth date should be positive... but I think I already find how... Let's try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare MMDD of today and the user's birthday. Then build the next birthday accordingly with the current or next year.

```
SELECT
  id, 
  next_birthday,
  DATEDIFF(next_birthday, NOW()) AS daystobd
FROM
(
  SELECT
    id, 
    datebirth, 
    CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(datebirth, '%m%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m%d')
      THEN CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()), '-', DATE_FORMAT(datebirth, '%m-%d'))
      ELSE CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()) + 1, '-', DATE_FORMAT(datebirth, '%m-%d'))
    END AS next_birthday
  FROM users
) data
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(next_birthday, NOW());
```

Comment: I had to completely rethink the problem, when I noticed you didn't only want the records sorted by days till next birthday, but also show the correct number of days. As some years are leap years and others are not, this is no one-liner, but should work for any case.

Answer (score 0):

Give them a weight if below 0

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN datstobd<0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,daystobd
```